# SQLiteException: no such table: en_table (code 1 SQLITE_ERROR)

Tags: java, android, sqlite

I searched a lot can't find fix this issue. Everything is alright with the code but i'm getting error: no such table: en_table

Can anyone can help me to fix this issue, i already wasted 3 hours to finding the solution for this but no success.

Here is the code:

```
private void queryString(String str, String subType) {
    switch (subType) {
        case "english":
            cursor = db.rawQuery("SELECT " + getWordColumnName() + " FROM " + getEnglishTableName() + " WHERE " + getWordColumnName()
                    + " LIKE '" + str + "%' AND " + getFreqColumnName() + " > 10 ORDER BY " + getFreqColumnName() + " DESC LIMIT 10", null);
            break;
        case "pashto":
            cursor = db.rawQuery("SELECT " + getWordColumnName() + " FROM " + getPashtoTableName() + " WHERE " + getWordColumnName()
                    + " LIKE '" + str + "%' AND " + getFreqColumnName() + " > 10 ORDER BY " + getFreqColumnName() + " DESC LIMIT 10", null);
            break;
        case "farsi":
            cursor = db.rawQuery("SELECT " + getWordColumnName() + " FROM " + getFarsiTableName() + " WHERE " + getWordColumnName()
                    + " LIKE '" + str + "%' AND " + getFreqColumnName() + " > 10 ORDER BY " + getFreqColumnName() + " DESC LIMIT 10", null);
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }
}


private String getEnglishTableName() {
    return mContext.getResources().getString("en_table");
}

.....
```

This is the error log:

```
2020-06-04 20:55:56.701 11863-12087/com.studio.customemojiapp W/System.err: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: no such table: en_table (code 1 SQLITE_ERROR): , while compiling: SELECT word FROM en_table WHERE word LIKE 'h%' AND freq > 10 ORDER BY freq DESC LIMIT 10
2020-06-04 20:55:56.702 11863-12087/com.studio.customemojiapp W/System.err:     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.nativePrepareStatement(Native Method)
2020-06-04 20:55:56.702 11863-12087/com.studio.customemojiapp W/System.err:     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.acquirePreparedStatement(SQLiteConnection.java:903)
2020-06-04 20:55:56.702 11863-12087/com.studio.customemojiapp W/System.err:     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.prepare(SQLiteConnection.java:514)
2020-06-04 20:55:56.703 11863-12087/com.studio.customemojiapp W/System.err:     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteSession.prepare(SQLiteSession.java:588)
2020-06-04 20:55:56.703 11863-12087/com.studio.customemojiapp W/System.err:     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteProgram.<init>(SQLiteProgram.java:58)
2020-06-04 20:55:56.703 11863-12087/com.studio.customemojiapp W/System.err:     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteQuery.<init>(SQLiteQuery.java:37)
2020-06-04 20:55:56.703 11863-12087/com.studio.customemojiapp W/System.err:     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDirectCursorDriver.query(SQLiteDirectCursorDriver.java:46)
2020-06-04 20:55:56.703 11863-12087/com.studio.customemojiapp W/System.err:     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.rawQueryWithFactory(SQLiteDatabase.java:1457)
2020-06-04 20:55:56.703 11863-12087/com.studio.customemojiapp W/System.err:     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.rawQuery(SQLiteDatabase.java:1387)
2020-06-04 20:55:56.703 11863-12087/com.studio.customemojiapp W/System.err:     at com.studio.customemojiapp.database.DatabaseManager.queryString(DatabaseManager.java:61)
2020-06-04 20:55:56.703 11863-12087/com.studio.customemojiapp W/System.err:     at com.studio.customemojiapp.database.DatabaseManager.getAllRow(DatabaseManager.java:41)
2020-06-04 20:55:56.703 11863-12087/com.studio.customemojiapp W/System.err:     at com.studio.customemojiapp.android.SoftKeyboard$SelectDataTask.doInBackground(SoftKeyboard.java:1050)
2020-06-04 20:55:56.703 11863-12087/com.studio.customemojiapp W/System.err:     at com.studio.customemojiapp.android.SoftKeyboard$SelectDataTask.doInBackground(SoftKeyboard.java:1034)
2020-06-04 20:55:56.704 11863-12087/com.studio.customemojiapp W/System.err:     at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:333)
2020-06-04 20:55:56.704 11863-12087/com.studio.customemojiapp W/System.err:     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
2020-06-04 20:55:56.704 11863-12087/com.studio.customemojiapp W/System.err:     at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:245)
2020-06-04 20:55:56.704 11863-12087/com.studio.customemojiapp W/System.err:     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1167)
2020-06-04 20:55:56.704 11863-12087/com.studio.customemojiapp W/System.err:     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:641)
2020-06-04 20:55:56.704 11863-12087/com.studio.customemojiapp W/System.err:     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:764)
2020-06-04 20:55:56.704 11863-12087/com.studio.customemojiapp E/DB ERROR: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: no such table: en_table (code 1 SQLITE_ERROR): , while compiling: SELECT word FROM en_table WHERE word LIKE 'h%' AND freq > 10 ORDER BY freq DESC LIMIT 10
```

Comment: the error message is quite clear, no such table: en_table , you don't have a table called "en_table"

Comment: The code you posted throws the error but the problem is elsewhere. Post the code that creates the table.

Comment: @bashir it's already in db file

Comment: do you have only one database or more?

Comment: create table is in the db file

Comment: only one database

Comment: https://imgur.com/YVDReA1 you check the db structure

Comment: please share the code of how do you connect to the database and how you run the query, and do you tried to execute other queries on other tables (or even the same) and it worked?

Comment: dbhelper.class : https://raw.githubusercontent.com/maihannijat/AndroidKeyboard/master/app/src/main/java/com/sunzala/afghankeyboard/database/DatabaseHelper.java
dbmanager.class: https://raw.githubusercontent.com/maihannijat/AndroidKeyboard/master/app/src/main/java/com/sunzala/afghankeyboard/database/DatabaseManager.java

Comment: yes - i tried other queries but not working

Comment: there is a button called edit, you can press on it to add this extra information (the code in links), also I still can't see how you're executing the query (not how it is defined, but how you are calling the method)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/215324/discussion-between-ahsen-mughal-and-bashir).